# Dynamic Keys with array Values using UseState()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wanna be able to create a hashmap using a javascript object with dynamic keys using useState in react hooks. What I figured so far is that to append a new key value pair, I can just do the following:

```
const [map, setMap] = useState({});
setMap({...map, [key]:[value]});
```

But then, how would you be able to push onto that array? After doing some research, I tried doing the following two methods:

```
setMap({...map, [key]: [...[key], value]})
```

and

```
setMap({...map, [key]: [...map[key], value]})
```

But both don't work. The former just gives me the actual key with the value appended, meaning it is forever stuck to just two values(which is not what I want because I want to be able to push multiple values onto the array).

The Latter just gives me a an error stating that map[key] is not iterable, which is also quite confusing to me since when I console log map[key], it gives me the object with correct key value pair (albeit with only 2 items in the array, which is just the key and the latest value).

So how would you correctly push values onto this array? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second version is close. It will work if `map[key]` is already set

But otherwise `map[key]` is undefined, and trying to spread `[...undefined]` will give you the not iterable error

You can first define the currentValues, and if none use an empty array

```
const addValueToMap = (key, newValue) => {
  const currentValues = map[key] || []; // get current values for the key, or use empty array
  setMap({ ...map, [key]: [...currentValues, newValue] })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It went over my head how map[key] would initially be undefined, thus the error I was getting.